# Beyond compare output option

Tags: command, output, html-select, bc, beyondcompare

In beyond compare output-options:html-color instead of HTML I want to save as plain text.so,what parameter I need to give,please help

Wanted output as text file instead of HTML

Comment: This is not about programming, so is off-topic here. Please try on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).  You also need to post more information.  For example, where is the output-options  (I cant find them)?

Answer (score 1):

To output to plain text in a Beyond Compare script, omit "output-options" entirely.

Instead of:

```
folder-report layout:side-by-side output-to:out.html output-options:html-color
```

Use:

```
folder-report layout:side-by-side output-to:out.txt
```

For more info, see: [Beyond Compare Help - Scripting Reference](https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?scripting_reference.html)